# Alter Hibernate transaction timeout for only one method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Is there a way to alter the [Hibernate default transaction timeout](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#setTimeout-int-) value for only one method in a Spring Boot 2 JPA Repository? I want to keep the default 30s for my application (which contains both JPA Repositories and legacy repositories using a Hibernate SessionFactory), but allow a job (**EDIT:** taking place in a standalone transaction) that usually takes considerably more to be run. I'm wondering whether there is a way to specify exceptional situations, like you can except [Transactions from rollbacking in certain situations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

I am looking for a solution that does not require creating a different HibernateTransactionManager than I use for the other methods.

Comment: You can only do it per transaction so if that method is causing the transaction to be started you can change that. It should be doable with an annotation on that method - I'd check out `@Transactional(timeout = 30)` and if you want to always run that method in its own transaction I'd add `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: @Thomas will this override the default timeout?

Comment: Yes, this is specifically meant to override the default timeout. The JavaDoc should help here and I'd point out this portion again (emphasis by me): "Exclusively designed for use with Propagation.REQUIRED or Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW since _it only applies to newly startedtransactions_."

Comment: @Thomas this is the right answer to my question. Could you add an answer so I can mark is at accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has a `@Transactional` annotation which is used to mark methods (and thus scopes) that should run in a transactional context. This annotation has a `timeout` attribute which can be used to override the default timeout.

Note that the timeout can only be set at transaction level and thus the `timeout` attribute is only used when the annotation causes a new transaction to be started. The documentation specifically states: "Exclusively designed for use with Propagation.REQUIRED or Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW since it only applies to newly startedtransactions."

`Propagation.REQUIRED` would only cause a new transaction to be started when there's not already an active one so if you want to make sure the timeout is set, you need to start a new transaction and thus best use `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.

The annotation would thus be: `@Transactional(timeout = 30, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`