# Spring @Transactional with timeoutString value from a configuration property bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

We would like for specific methods to configure a different transaction timeout. Example:

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("app.transactions")
public class TransactionProperties {
  private Duration myServiceTransactionTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
}
```

and annotate the service with:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Transactional(timeoutString = "#{transactionProperties.myServiceTransactionTimeout.getSeconds()}")
  public Response exampleTransaction() {
     return doSomethingWithinTransaction();
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, the *SpEL* seems not to work. It turned out that Spring's `AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource` is implementing `EmbeddedValueResolverAware`, but there is no `StringValueResolver` assigned. Tested with Spring Boot 3.2.0.

Question: What do we need to change so that for methods transaction timeouts are configurable?

Comment: `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` might need to be set in order to enforce isolated transaction which affects the timeout, also. More info can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/tx-propagation.html#tx-propagation-requires_new). [This answer seems to be addressing the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69628689/6519224).

Comment: No, it's not about forcing a transaction to be created and a timeout to be set, it's about making time-out configuration configurable using configurations. It is possible to have individual time-out configurations per method, but it's not configurable. Example: `@Transactional(timeout = 5)`. Propagation is by default `REQUIRED` which by default creates a new transaction if not already existing. => The question is about `StringValueResolver` which seems not be injected by default by Spring.

Comment: That won't work. It will only resolve value expressions not full blown spel expressions. So using the actual name of the property in the `application.properties` (or where ever you placed it) will work.

Comment: Yes, it works with value expressions. We tried to find a solution where we can define a value using `Duration` or `Period`. This helps to make it more clear, what unit has this value (e.g. seconds `5s`, minute `5m`, ...). So if full blown spel is not supported, this can be solved by adding the unit name to the property name: `app.transaction.myServiceTransactionTimeoutInSec=5` and use it as `@Transactional(timeoutString="${app.transaction.myServiceTransactionTimeoutInSec}")`

Answer (score 2):

As far as we can see, full SpEL is not available here. The requirement can be achieved with an `int` instead of a `Duration` or `Period` object:

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("app.transactions")
public class TransactionProperties {
  private int myServiceTransactionTimeoutInSeconds = 5;
}
```

and

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Transactional(timeoutString = "${app.transactions.myServiceTransactionTimeoutInSeconds}")
  public Response exampleTransaction() {
     return doSomethingWithinTransaction();
  }

}
```